# undefined method 'configure' inside the initializer? added a new ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I installed the gem Bitly into my rails app

I did it by running `gem install bitly`

then I manually added `gem 'bitly'` into my gemfile

I created this inside `config\initializers\bitly.rb

```
Bitly.configure do |config|
  config.api_version = 3
  config.login = "myusername"
  config.api_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
end
```

I'm trying to get my rails server running but I get this error I've never seen before

```
Exiting
C:/app/config/initializers/bitly.rb:1:in `<top (
required)>': undefined method `configure' for Bitly:Module (NoMethodError)
```

How can I resolve this issue and make this gem work?

I am trying to use the gem inside one of my models

```
bitly.shorten("http://mydomain.com/article/#{id}")
```

Comment: Yeah, the documentation and source code don't appear to match up.  Maybe try using the `v3` branch.  You could initialize your Bitly client as a global in your initializer (it's essentially not much different than what `Bitly.configure { |config| ... }` would do anyways).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitly is currently available in version 0.8.1 on rubygems. This version does not support `Bitly.configure`. I recomend you use the gem from github, until someone releases a newer version on rubygems.

The bitly line in your `Gemfile` should look like this:

```
gem "bitly", :git => 'https://github.com/philnash/bitly/'
```

Then do a `bundle install` and bitly should work the way you expect.

Edit: There is even [a github issue](https://github.com/philnash/bitly/issues/40) for that error :)